# forcing download of tar.xz results in corrupt file in php

Tags: php, linux, download

IF i download filename.tra.xz it courrupted.

```
$newfile=$row['orginal_filename']; //download file name
$download_file='Attachment/'.$row['path'];
header('Content-type: application/x-gzip');
//header("Content-Type: application/forcedownload");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($download_file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $newfile . '"');
readfile($download_file);
exit();
```

Comment: add first you could change the Content-Type to application/x-xz (I don't that it will make a big difference but Wikipedia Listed it as Mime-Type for .xz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archive_formats

Comment: anyway, do you know which part is corrupted? We need more infos. Is the file empty? Maybe your webserver killed the connection due a timeout?